# Understanding the method apply() in Pandas series and dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I am trying to understand how the method `apply()` can be used with series and dataframes.

As shown below, when the `np.max()` function is used with the `apply()` method with the dataframe it is returning the max value for each column. But when used with the series, it is just returning the series. My expectation was that it would return the max value of the series. That is, the result would be similar to `series.max()`. Why is `apply()` performing differently on series and on dataframes?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   

 
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,3)), columns = list('ABC'))
my_df

Output:
    A   B   C
0   2   4   7
1   9   6   6
2   4   4   8
3   8   8   1


df_max = my_df.apply(np.max)
df_max

Output:
A    9
B    8
C    8
dtype: int32

se_max = my_df['A'].apply(np.max)
se_max

Output:
0    2
1    9
2    4
3    8
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Comment: When you apply on the series you apply `np.max(2)` for first item, etc. which returns it unchanged. The equivalent to the first code would be `np.max(df['A'])`

Comment: Do not inser picture. If it is code: please write the code in the question (just copy paste). In such manner we can copy your text and give an answer. With images we just skip the question (too much effort). And this is a reference site, so every question should have all information (also in 10 years), so if you need to include image you should embed it. Do not expect programmers clicks random links from random people.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `apply` works along the first dimension of the object. In a dataframe, the first dimension is vertical, and `apply` applies the function to each column. In a series, the first (and the only) dimension is horizontal, and `apply` applies the function to each row.